# ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead: array=[0. 2. 4. ... 2. 4. 3.]

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, reshape, valueerror

*Test_train split:*

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.30, random_state = 10)
```

Test train values are: X_train = (36201, 32) X_test = (15516, 32) y_ train = (36201,) y_test = (15516,)

*

```
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis
model_lda = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()
model_lda.fit(y_train, X_train)
```

Error i am getting:

> ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
> array=[0. 2. 4. ... 2. 4. 3.].
> Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to always write a minimal, reproducible example. It helps a lot in resolving errors.

Looking at your `model_lda.fit`, X and y should be inverted:
`model_lda.fit(X_train, y_train)`.

You can check the documentation of `LinearDiscriminantAnalysis` [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis.html#sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis.fit).